# How to create class with jQuery by parsing the class information

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a class on the page by finding classes that start with "f" and end with a number and then writing that style to the head tag using the number as font-size.  I'm stuck on finding class, and parsing out number into a variable to use.  It can be on any element, div, p, a, span, td, body or whatever.  Here is what I have so far.

```js
/* if class starts with f and has number, add class 
with font size of that in pixels and make it important */

//creates variable for the number
var number = function() {
  //lost here...!
};

//prints style to head tag
$("<style>")
  .prop("type", "text/css")
  .html(".f" + number + "{font-size: " + number + "px !important;}")
  .appendTo("head");
```

```html
<div class="f30">I'm 30 pixels in text size</div>
<div class="f60">I'm 60 pixels in text size</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to concatenate the `number` function instead of calling it with arguments?

Comment: whatever you suggest I'm happy to look at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to loop over all the elements whose class starts with `f`. Then loop over all the classes in the element to find the ones that are of the form `f<number>`. Then add all those sizes to the stylesheet.

```js
var sizes_seen = {}; // To prevent duplicates
var styles = '';
$("[class^=f]").each(function() {
  $.each(this.className.split(' '), function(i, cl) {
    var result = cl.match(/^f(\d+)$/)
    if (result && !(result[1] in sizes_seen)) {
      var fontsize = result[1];
      sizes_seen[fontsize] = true;
      styles += '.f' + fontsize + '{font-size: ' + fontsize + 'px !important;}';
    }
  });
});
$("<style>", {
  type: "text/css",
  html: styles
}).appendTo("head");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f30">I'm 30 pixels in text size</div>
<div class="f60">I'm 60 pixels in text size</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster and simpler to just create a loop and generate the style rules without worrying about searching the DOM which is the expensive part of what you are trying to do

```
var style ='';
for(i=1; i <= 100; i++){
  style += ".f" + i+ "{font-size: " + i+ "px !important;}\n";
}

$('<style>').text(style).appendTo('head');
```

This would create rules for classes `f1` to `f100`

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: ah yes started doing something like this and wasn't working - will try it in a second and let you know!

Comment: would also make sense to copy it to a style sheet and get rid of the script. Won't have flickers on page load.  http://jsfiddle.net/dxvhtz0m/

Comment: copy all f1 to f100 to stylesheet? that's what I was trying to remove actually... this kind of treatment is just used as an override on the fly.  Your script works but there's a space between + and = you have to remove....

Comment: but is more efficient having styles there when browser renders elements. Then they render immediately to right size instead of waiting for script to activate. I guess you could use `document.write` in the head though instead of using jQuery

Comment: k so this obviously works - but is there an easy way to just add the styles needed to the head - rather than all 1-100?  So if there's `<p class="f10">`, `<span class="f45">` it would just add the 2 necessary styles due to the fact they exist on the page?

Comment: But is far more expensive searching through the DOM to find those classes than it is to output extras. I doubt you need to go down to `1` or up to `100`. Those were arbitrary limits

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) you can get a list of all elements that start "f". However that seems like more work and more complicated than just defining the the styles for .f30 and .f60 in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can go, however you probably need one of those two:

Generate classes for a discrete amount of different font sizes

```
var myFontSizes = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
var styles = '';
for (var i = 0; i < myFontSizes.length ; i++)
{
   styles += '.f' + myFontSizes[i] + '{font-size: ' + myFontSizes[i] + 'px !important;} '
}
$("<style>")
   .prop("type", "text/css")
   .html(styles)
   .appendTo("head");
```

Or the huge amount of fonts form **minFont** to **maxFont**

```
var styles = '';
var minFont = 1;
var maxFont = 100;
for (var i = minFont; i <= minFont ; i++)
{
    styles += '.f' + i + '{font-size: ' + i + 'px !important;} '
}

$("<style>")
   .prop("type", "text/css")
   .html(styles)
   .appendTo("head");
```